# Is it possible to set different email Text for "Decline" action in Docusign/API

Tags: docusignapi

I am using docusign for sending out document to be signed by the user.

I see that i have an option to set the Content of email for recipients that they receive.

I am trying to see if I can customize the email content when user "Declines" a document.

For example:
I wanted the sender to see as "The customer has declined the document"
and the customer should see "The document is successfully declined"

is this possible if so please provide additional information or reference to online would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to customize the emails that DocuSign sends in response to the "Envelope Declined" event, such that the email that the Sender receives is different than the email that the Signer (Recipient) receives.  You can achieve this by customizing the **Email Resource File** (as described in this guide: https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/docusign-system-default-email-formats.pdf).

Customizing the Recipient's "Envelope Declined" email is described on page 30 of the guide, customizing the Sender's "Envelope Declined" email is described on page 94 of the guide.

(Keep in mind that an **Email Resource File** is associated with a "**Brand**" -- so any changes you apply to an Email Resource File will apply to all Envelopes sent using the corresponding Brand.)

Comment: The document reference is very helpful. But have been stuck with one additional question inline with the previous one. Is it possible to restrict the email being sent out to the recipients? For example, i create an envelope with 4 recipients. Is there a way to control only two recipient should receive the email in one scenario. In other scenario i want the other two to receive the email? I read about marking recipient as embedded. But that would prevent them from getting any emails right? Thanks for reading.

Comment: It's not possible to make DocuSign send emails to some of the remote (i.e., non-embedded) recipients and not to others.  If you designate a recipient as embedded/captive, then you (i.e., your application) will be responsible for all email communication with the recipient (except for the "Envelope Complete" email, which you can specifically enable or disable for embedded recipients using setting in Preferences >> Features).  In the "embedded/captive signing" scenario, your app must alert the signer when it's their turn to sign and also provide a means to access the envelope via your app.